# Regex to remove c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove some string from regex in c#.

I have a string

```
000603ABC140702-005051-I-FILL200-NNYYNY180319-142110-A2002.zip
```

From this I want to remove those strings

> 140702
>
> 142110

And I want a result as

```
000603ABC-005051-I-FILL200-NNYYNY180319--A2002.zip
```

How can I do that in regex?

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? `string.Replace` seems much more efficient here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Regex.Replace method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
 var regex = new Regex("(140702)|(142110)");
 var result = regex.Replace("000603ABC140702-005051-I-FILL200-NNYYNY180319-142110-A2002.zip", "");
```

Although, as already stated by @CompuChip, String.Replace would probably be more efficient in this case. There's a discussion of various methods of replacing substrings and their efficiency at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debuggingtoolbox/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance/.

Comment: the values 140702 & 142110 are not constant one but the position is constant. The 2 values are datetime of the file creation,

Comment: Is any of the filename the same every time?

Comment: Have you actually tried running that code? It doesn't do what you claim... THe output it generates is `63ABC-55-I-FILL-NNYYNY839--A.zip`. The regex is using character classes so it is in fact matching all numbers 01247 and removing them (as well as | but that's not relevant). I think you might have actually meant: `new Regex("(140702|142110)");`

Comment: @Karthikeyan: So you actually want to remove the characters at positions 10-15 and the same for the latter ones no matter what they are? If so that should really be specified in your question and lends itself even more to string manipulation such as substring than regular expressions (though regex could still do the job).

Comment: @Chris, you're right! Sorry... Will update the example.

Comment: @Loki: You don't want the square brackets at all! That edit still leaves it doing exactly the same as it did before. Go look at what `[]` does in a regular expression - it matches a single character that is anything from the set of characters included in the `[]`. So now it will match any character that is in the set `01247()|` - all you've done is made it match `()` as well as the characters it was matching before!